# Store the wordpress "featured image" under »wp_posts« Database table

Tags: database, post-thumbnails

How to store the WordPress featured image under the `wp_posts` table. Can any one help me?

The reason why I am asking same table details (`wp_posts`), is because I am using a JSON response to add in my android application.  So I would like to save featured image also under `wp_posts` table.

[image]

Comment: Images are already saved as post type `attachment` to the `wp_posts` table, so you are able to get you featured image from there, if you know the corresponding ID.

Comment: @ialocin you should post that as an answer ;-)

Comment: @ialocin in wp-post featured image is not storing , i updated my table structure screenshot please check it. Thank you

Comment: too late I guess :) @PieterGoosen I left you a message in The Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not change anything in the DB structure of wordpress as this is essentially the same as hacking the core.

You should simply write your own json end points which provide you with the relevant info.